# ERROR as :Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments in visual force

Tags: visualforce

Can any one help me on this. I have a visual force page created in PDF format. Based on the Condition i need to Display the Value.

1)If the product line for the product selected in opportunity items is equal to ‘ DIE’ make following changes .

a) unit price should change to $0.01. ---Condition Works

b)Extension =Qty*0.01--Condition Works

**c)Subtotal =(Non_pick_total)**

But Extension is formula field which is (Extension=qty*1) and

Non_pick_total is a Roll up summary field which Aggregates the Extension.

```
The issue is the "Extension" field value is getting calculated based on the formula field but it should get calculated as per the changes made in visual force page and display (Extension =Qty*0.01) on the subtotal .
```

CODE :

```
if(OPplineitem[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c=='DIE') 
                     {
                      tempObj.unitprice=0.01;
                      tempobj.extension=OPplineitem[i].Quantity * tempObj.unitprice;
                      tempObj.productname=OPplineitem[i].Bin_Item_Code__c;

                      tempObj.Subtotal =opportunity.Non_Pick_Total__c*tempObj.unitprice;

                     }
                 else
                     {
                     tempObj.unitprice=1;
                     //tempObj.unitprice=OPplineitem[i].ListPrice;
                     tempobj.extension=OPplineitem[i].Extension__c;
                    }

I Get Error As :Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments at line
tempObj.Subtotal =opportunity.Non_Pick_Total__c*tempObj.unitprice;
```

Here Subtotal and Non_Pick_Total are the field from Opportunity.I  got stucked at point c.
Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: I believe the question is: what data types are the fields Subtotal, Non_Pick_Total__c and unitprice ?

Comment: @MihaiNeagoe:Subtotal and Non_Pick_Total__c are Roll-Up Summary (SUM Opportunity Product ) and UnitPrice is a Currency.